# Как в MySQL 5.0 удалить поле в таблице, при условии что поле существует?

Tags: mysql

Как в MySQL 5.0 удалить поле в таблице, при условии что поле существует? Делаю так:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS `col_name`;
```

Не работает, пишет синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: проще в phpmyadmin и не парься.

Comment: В моём случае есть sql файл, который может выполняться несколько раз, так что думаю не проще

Answer (score 1):

Одним запросом никак. Сначала проверить наличие поля, затем только удалять.

**UPD.**

На [PL/SQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) это будет выглядеть так:

```
IF SHOW COLUMNS table_name LIKE 'col_name' THEN    ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN col_name;END IF;
```

На любом другом языке:Cначала выполнить `SHOW COLUMNS table_name LIKE 'col_name'`, если была возвращена хотя бы одна строка, то выполнить `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN col_name`

Comment: Напишите как это будет выглядеть в sql